# Trouble with css Container Queries in React Styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Does anyone have any examples of getting css container queries working with the styled-components package? I can't get the css within the query to even show up.

I tried a few things. Below is the one I thought would most work. I can't see the styles within the container queries applied at all. I double checked that the "ImageWrapper" component has the right class indicated in the container query.

It also did not work to put the container query within the "RightContent" component, with or without the & (to refer to the image wrapper parent).

```js
<RightContent>
  <ImageWrapper className="imageWrapper">
   {s3_image && (
    <Image
     style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
     imgStyle={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
     src={s3_image?.filename}
     alt={s3_image?.alt}
     />
    )}
   </ImageWrapper>
</RightContent>
.
.
.
const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  max-width: 100%;
`;

const RightContent = styled.div`
  container: rightContent inline-size;

  @container rightContent (min-width: 633px) {
    .imageWrapper {
      aspect-ratio: 3/2;
      border: 5px solid red;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Looks like `styled-components` does not support `container-queries`, yet

Comment: version beta 6 has support for it: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.6

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by injecting a style tag into the component where I override what's declared in the styled component:

```
<style type="text/css">
   {`
       #widget-${widgetId} {
          container-type: inline-size;
          container-name: widget;
        }
        @container widget (max-width: 480px) {
          .widget-content {
             grid-template-columns: 1fr !important;
           }
           .widget-form {
             grid-template-columns: 1fr !important;
           }
         }
   `}
 </style>
```